# What does "getting a little distance" mean?

Tags: meaning

Two bikers, Billy and Wyatt sit by the campfire:

> Wyatt: What's the matter? You zonked? You really zoaned?
>
> Billy: No, I'm just kinda tired, man.
>
> Wyatt: Oh, man, you're pulling inside. You're **getting a little
> distance** tonight.

What does "getting a little distance" mean?

Source: Easy Rider (1969).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint is given to you in the sentence before:

> You're pulling inside *[you are closing yourself to me/us]*. You're getting a little distance *[you are becoming/getting a little [distant/reserved]](https://www.google.com/search?q=distant%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB888GB888&biw=1372&bih=661&sxsrf=ALeKk03if0NmgnzFxSWL20YQp1ASBzlOBw%3A1626772822357&ei=VpX2YIe9Fcb9gAbBioy4Bg&oq=distant%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBQgAEJECMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgQIABBDMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIECAAQQzIGCAAQBxAeSgQIQRgAUPGzAVjxswFgoMwBaABwAngAgAFMiAHMAZIBATOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiHwNOBqfHxAhXGPsAKHUEFA2c4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5)* tonight.

Answer (score 1):

He is getting distanced from reality, from the real world of his friends, the fire, the bike. He is not grounded.